# Android use object in registerForActivityResult

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult, registerforactivityresult

In my `AppCompatActivity`, I declared an `ActivityResultLauncher`. I used `registerForActivityResult()` to create it and passed a `LambdaExpression` for the `ActivityResultCallback`.

However, I need a reference to an object in this `ActivityResultCallback`, which I have when calling `launch()`.

Example code:

```
private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launcher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
    object.doSomething();
});

method() {
    Object object = new Object();
    launcher.launch(new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class));
}
```

I could just save the object in a `private` field, but is this what Android intents us to do?

I understand that Android does not want you to share objects between different activities. But here, the reference should only be kept in my `MainActivity.class`.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could just save the object in a private field, but is this what Android intents us to do?

Yes, pretty much yes. Look at the fragment in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result):

> `registerForActivityResult()` is safe to call before your fragment or activity is created, allowing it to be used directly when declaring member variables for the returned `ActivityResultLauncher` instances.

So it seems like the `ActivityResultCallback` is supposed to reference the declared instance variables, so You indeed

> could just save the object in a private field

and it would be fine. The reference to that object would be `private` and it would, obviously, exist only in Your `MainActivity`.

Comment: Thank you, good to know I always did it as intended.